# Finding all numbers that can be generated with $\frac{1}{x + y}$

Tags: number-theory

Let's say you are given an empty set that can only be filled with real numbers. Say that 1 is now in the set. The only other numbers that can be in the set are the only ones that can be generated with the expression $\frac{1}{x + y}$ where x and y are numbers that are in the set(x and y can be the same). How would you characterize all the numbers in the set? What if the starting number was irrational, like $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please put these facts in your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning. ¶ Interesting question, so it's worth improving.

Comment: Also, this question is unclear: "How would you express all the numbers in the set?" Do you mean, how would you characterize the numbers in the set without arbitrary recursion?

Comment: @BrianTung Yes I mean characterize and this is not homework.

Comment: @babyaids: Fine! But maybe you could say in your post what may have led you to this question.

Answer (score 7):

Let $S_\alpha \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be the minimal set such that $\alpha \in S_\alpha$ and, for any $x,y \in S_\alpha$ we have $\frac{1}{x+y} \in S_\alpha$. As a partial answer, here's how to find $S_1$.

First, we claim that $S_1 \subseteq \mathbb{Q}\cap[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$. It is indeed clear that $S_1 \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$. Let us see that $S_1 \subseteq[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$.

Suppose, towards a contradiction, that $S_1 \nsubseteq[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$. Order the elements of $S_1$ as $S_1 = \{s_1,s_2, s_3, \dots\}$ in such a way that $s_n = \frac{1}{s_i + s_j}$ for $i, j < n$. Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ be the first integer such that $s_n \notin [\frac{1}{2}, 1]$. Then we have $s_n = \frac{1}{s_i+s_j} \geq \frac{1}{1+1} = \frac{1}{2}$, and similarly $s_n = \frac{1}{s_i+s_j} \leq \frac{1}{1/2+1/2} = 1$. This contradicts our assumption, and so we must have $S_1 \subseteq [\frac{1}{2},1]$.

Next, we show that $S_1 \supseteq \mathbb{Q}\cap[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$. We want to show that, provided $\frac{a}{b} \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1]$, then $\frac{a}{b} \in S_1$. We assume that $a$ and $b$ are coprime. We argue by induction on the integer $b$. The base case, $b = 1$, is clear, as $1 \in S_1$. So let $b \geq 2$, and we have $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{1}{b/a} = \frac{1}{\frac{\lceil b/2 \rceil}{a} +\frac{\lfloor b/2 \rfloor}{a}}$. But both $\frac{\lceil b/2 \rceil}{a}$ and $\frac{\lfloor b/2 \rfloor}{a}$ are in $S_1$ by induction, as $a < b$ and $\frac{\lceil b/2 \rceil}{a}$ is easily seen to lie inside $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$, so we are done.

Answer (score 2):

Let me reformulate the question to match what I think you mean.
Let $S$ be the smallest set of real numbers with the following properties:

1. A given nonzero real number $\alpha$ is in $S$.
2. If $x$ and $y$ are in $S$, then $1/(x+y)$ is in $S$.

You would like to characterize $S$.

Note that $S$ can be produced by the following iterative procedure. Start with
the singleton $S_0 = \{\alpha\}$, and define a sequence of sets $S_n$ by the following process:
$$ S_{n+1} = S_n \cup \left\{ \frac{1}{s+t}: s, t \in S_n\right\}$$
Then $$ S = \bigcup_n S_n $$

I don't know a complete answer, but I can say this: every member of $S$ is of the form $p(\alpha)/q(\alpha)$, where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials with nonnegative integer coefficients, and degrees that differ by $1$.

EDIT: Also $p/q$ is an odd function.

Comment: Another requirement is that $p(\alpha)/q(\alpha)$ must evaluate to $1/\sqrt{2}$ at $\alpha = 1/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: How do you know that every member of S is of the form $p(\alpha)/q(\alpha)$?

Comment: @babyaids Induction on $n$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Can you explain further I am a bit confused on that part?

Comment: $\alpha = \alpha/1$ where $p(\alpha) = \alpha$ and $q(\alpha) = 1$.  If $x = p(\alpha)/q(\alpha)$ and $y = r(\alpha)/s(\alpha)$ where $p, q, r, s$ are polynomials with nonnegative integer coefficients then 
$$ \frac{1}{x+y} = \frac{q(\alpha) s(\alpha)}{p(\alpha) s(\alpha) + r(\alpha) q(\alpha)}$$
where $q s$ and $ps + rq$ are polynomials with nonnegative integer coefficients.